# Passing Dart objects to js functions in js interop

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I've been playing around a bit with the new js interop of dart. So far everything was very straight-forward. But one thing I'm not sure about is how to deal with js stuff like this:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  showMathMenu: false
  .. many other different options
});
```

I can translate the MathJax.Hub.Config part:

```
@JS('MathJax') external MathJaxClass get MathJax;
class MathJaxClass {
  external HubClass get Hub;
}

@JS('MathJax.Hub')
class HubClass {
  external void Config(options);
}
```

But now I would like to have the `options` argument of `Config` function to be a Dart Object. I'm not sure how to do this. The only way, I can get something working is with a `Map`:

```
  MathJax.Hub.Config(new JsObject.jsify({
    'showProcessingMessages': false,
    'showMathMenu': false
  }));
```

But this is surely not ideal. Any ideas?

Comment: What argument(s) does the JS function `Hub.Config()` expect?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer One argument. Just a regular Javascript object with only data. Every key is just a string.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is as follows:

```
@anonymous
@JS()
class Config {
  external bool get showProcessingMessages;
  external bool get showMathMenu;

  external factory Config({bool showProcessingMessages, bool showMathMenu});
}
```

Here the `Config` name is not matching any javascript name, so you can name it whatever you want. You can then call it like this:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config(new Config(
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  showMathMenu: false
));
```

The object passed to the js function, will be a regular javascript object:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since a recent update the `@anonymous` annotation is used to create JS objects from Dart classes instead of a factory constructor.

```
@JS()
@anonymous
class Config {
  external bool get showProcessingMessages;
  external set showProcessingMessages(bool value);
  external bool get showMathMenu;
  external set showMathMenu(bool value);
}

MathJax.Hub.Config(new Config()
  ..showProcessingMessages= false
  ..showMathMenu = false
}));
```